# Show that $E\subset F \Rightarrow \#E\leq\#F$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am new to proofs and am very uncertain about how detailed proofs should be.

I want to prove: $E\subset F \Rightarrow \#E\leq\#F$.

My proof:

By definition, if there exists an injection from $E$ to $F$, then $\#E\leq\#F$.

Because $E\subset F$, there exists an injection $f:E\rightarrow F$, where $f(x)=x$, and so $\#E\leq\#F$.

I'm not sure whether this is sufficient. Do I need further proof that $f$ exists?
And should I go on to prove that this function is in fact injective? Or are these things considered clear enough? I'm in an undergrad analysis class. Do these things perhaps depend on the lecturer?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not sure whether you need to prove something, that's a good enough reason to prove them.

Comment: Good point, but I feel like I would just go deeper and deeper through the layers until I eventually got down to the axioms... I've seen stated that in the exam, points will be given for "quality and correctness" of the proof. I'm afraid to come off as naive by proving too many elementary things, but am also afraid to not be detailed enough. I don't really have an intuition about it, and the only feedback will be the exam grade.

Comment: Well, in this case, you don't need to go much deeper. Proving that $f$ is injective takes no more than 30 seconds. And this is also the reason why you *should* prove it: because you don't know how complicated the proof is. If you do not see that, then you also do not know if the proof is trivial (and not necesary) or not. So you are basically in risk of loosing points.

Comment: The best thing you can do is do a lot of exercises, and in time, get an intuitive idea of what proof is simple and what proof is not.

Comment: Thank you, that's good advice, and probably the only good choice I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose a good approach. Because you exhibited $f$, there is no doubt such a function must exist. To most people, it should be reasonably obvious that $f(x)=x$ is an injection -- but I would ask your professor about whether this needs to be explicitly shown in this case or not.

Comment: Please, note that $f$ may not be a bijection, because we only know that $E\subset F$.  So $F$ may have elements that are not in the image of $f$.

Comment: @Ramiro yes... i just meant that it will be a bijection if the spaces are the same, i.e. $f$ can be considered as a map $f:F \to F$ since $E \subset F$...

Comment: @Ramiro took out the comment nevertheless to avoid confusion